# I want to make a transparent mesh for particle hair. Don't know how to call it correctly

Tags: mesh, particles, edit-mode

I'm newbie and not very familiar with definitions, so I could call something wrong.

How can I make an separate object with mesh like this (transparent) to use it for patricle hair system? I'm selecting faces of scalp I need, duplicate them and making them a separate object, but don't know how to make it's mesh transparent, with no material, just like at picture.

I've searched the web a lot, but all what I found is about making the material of mesh transparent. Maybe I just asked the wrong questions because don’t know how to call this option right.

Sorry for bad english, I'm not the native speaker.

Thank you in advance!

[image: bold girl who have what I need]

Comment: Is your goal to make a mesh that doesn't show up in the final render?

Comment: @andesign, not sure, i'll try to explain. I found this feature in mb-lab 1.7.7, in it you can add particle hair by pressing button. And it's appearing like an scalp with particle hair. But the thing is, when you delete particles from this scalp, it becomes visible, with defoult material. But when you add it back, the scalp in not visible anymore. And there is no option toched in parcticle settings. How can I do the same?